# PHP - cannot delete file

Tags: php

I try to delete a file which is in `/etc/scripts/`

First I created a demo file:

```
echo "test1234" > test.log
```

> -rw-r--r--  1 root root    5 Jul  3 13:15 test.log

Now I try to delete it by using PHP:

```
deleteFile();

function deleteFile()
{
    $file = "/etc/scripts/test.log";

    if (is_file($file)) {
        chmod($file, 0777);
        if (unlink($file)) {
            return "File '$file' deleted.";
        } else {
            return "File '$file' could not be deleted.";
        }
    } else {
        return "$file is not a file!";
    }
}
```

But I get `File '/etc/scripts/test.log' could not be deleted.` as response;

I also executed `chmod 777 test.log` on the file, same result.

Comment: check your user own the operation or not? This operation might be permitted to the `root`

Comment: You probably aren't targeting the file properly, maybe some path issue. Do `var_dump(file_exists($file));` first, inside the `deleteFile` function

Comment: did you do chmod 777 as root in the console? Doing it from php will not change anything (except if you have managed to get php to run as root)

Comment: Yes I did it also as root from the shell

Comment: @samayo, no I checked it by outputting the content with cat, the path is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only the file itself, but also the directory `/etc/scripts/` should be writable by the user who executes the script.

Comment: You are correct, I had to give the third group write permission, now it works :) But I will do it with `shell_exec('sudo rm PATH');` instead and make an entry for that file in the /etc/sudoers, its more secure than allowing public to write.